# Why dim of airpassengers dataset is Null in R?

Tags: r

I am not sure why this is, but the dim of Airpassengers dataset in R turns out to be null.

```r
data("AirPassengers")
dim(AirPassengers)
#NULL
```

I imported the data set into a CSV file and it turns out to be totally different from what we see in R. It is even missing the year and the month level details. Where is my understanding gap?

Comment: Please include the code that you used to read the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the `AirPassengers` object from the `datasets` package (`datasets::AirPassengers`).

This object is not a data.frame or matrix. It is a `ts` object. You can see the `?ts` help page for more info. Since this type of object does not store it's data in a 2D matrix, it does not respond to the the generic `dim()` function. If you want to know how many observations there are you can use `length()`

```
length(AirPassengers)
# [1] 144
```

Or you can can get basic info about the start period, end period, and period frequency with

```
tsp(AirPassengers)
# [1] 1949.000 1960.917   12.000
```

You can extract the `frequency()` of the observations per period which would give you the number of "columns"

```
frequency(AirPassengers)
# [1] 12
```

So you could write your own `dim()` for ts objects if you like.

```
dim.ts <- function(x) {
   c(length(x)/frequency(x), frequency(x))
}
dim(AirPassengers)
# [1] 12 12
```

Though this is slightly misleading because you cannot use matrix indexing to extract values form the `ts` object.